How does "legei" compare with "lalei" in Romans 3:19?
Romans 3:19 ESV

"Now we know that whatever the law says it speaks to those who are under the law, so that every mouth may be stopped, and the whole world may be held accountable to God." [says/legei and speaks/lalei]

The ESV makes a difference between these two Greek words.
Romans 3:19 KJB

"Now we know that what things soever the law saith, it saith to them who are under the law: that every mouth may be stopped, and all the world may become duilty before God."

The KJB does not make a difference between them.
Does the difference between legei and lalei suggest that those under the law do not have "ears to hear", or how else might the difference between these two be described in this verse? ["ears to hear" Matthew 11:15].

The two words are almost exact synonyms and Paul uses the different words to break a prolix monotony.

@Dottard As I put in my answer. and to quote Trench's 'Synonyms'- "at Rom 3:19 there is an instructive interchange of the words." I have a great respect for Trench and not once in 'Synonyms' have I found that he explains synonyms in the N.T. with the sense of "to break a prolix monotony."

I immediately thought:  the words are just synonyms.  But, then I looked at the text and noticed something.
The ὄτι clause is structured as a parallelism.
ὅσα      ὁ νόμος λέγει 
τοῖς ἐν τῷ νόμῳ  λαλεῖ

Said in Greek, it kind of rolls off the tongue--it’s poetic.  The two parts even have the same number of syllables.  I got thoughtful.
So, I think there may be something to highlighting the subtle difference between the two words.
However, stressing the similarity of the two words is important.  In English, if I say, “It says what it says,” I’m actually using two, slightly different meanings of the word ‘says’.  You can see that in sentence when you try to understand what that sentence actually means.  Doesn’t it mean, “It means what it means.”?  Or, does it mean, “It says what it means”?  Or, is it, “It means what it says.”?  I’m hoping you get what I mean by what I’m saying.  :-)  These two words, in English or Greek, are intimate friends.  We can't apply the difference everywhere.
But, maybe here we can.  And maybe, given the parallelism, we should.  I suggest the following as a way to capture the meaning-intent of the parallel structure:

So, we know that whatever the Law means, it speaks what it means to
those under the dominion of the Law.

That is Paul making a declarative statement about the Law.    He says the Law means what it means to everyone “under Law” that it speaks to.  It’s a declarative statement because Paul started with the word, Οἴδαμεν (“We conceptually know...”).  Paul had actually developed the “everyone is held to the law standard” point a few moments earlier (2:12-16).  So, we now know it.  And here he coalesces that previous explanation, which involved two groups of people, Jews and non-Jews, into one group, πᾶς ὁ κόσμος (“the entire world”). And he applies the simple phrase ἐν τῷ νόμῳ (“in the Law” or “under the dominion of the Law”) to that single group.
Paul then immediately follows that with a ἴνα clause.
Margaret Gavin Sim, in her PhD thesis, “A  Relevance Theoretic approach to the particle ἴνα in Koine Greek” says: “[ἴνα] alerts the reader to expect an interpretation of the thought of the speaker or implied author.”  Her point is that ἵνα isn’t so much a “so that” conjunction, as it is a “here’s the way I want you to understand what I just said” conjunction.
How’s that apply?
Per Sim, and Paul’s use of ἵνα, Paul's statement is immediately followed by an interpretation of what that statement means.  And I believe this will bring to the surface how Paul has leveraged the difference between λέγω and λαλέω.
So, what’s Paul’s interpretation of what he just said?
Paul says the following:

Every single person in the entire world does not get to speak back.
Instead they all are held accountable to God. (3:19b)
διότι (conjunction; because) Because you can’t show justification
(δικαιόω) by performing the Law. (3:20a)
γάρ (conjunction; for, signals that strengthening information
follows), and διά (preposition with genitive; through, expressing
agent)  for the Law’s purpose was to be an agent through which one
obtains procedural/relational knowledge (ἐπίγνωσις) of sin. (3:20b)

In other words, Paul’s explanation gives the meaning of the Law.  It means two things:

It’s there to make sin real in people’s lives (the δὶα γὰρ clause)
It’s not there for people to obtain justification before the God who
they are accountable to (the διότι clause).

The result being:  everyone has nothing at all that they can say, πᾶν στόμα φραγῇ (“every mouth shut”).  The point being:  everyone needs to find a different way to be justified.  The Law way won’t work.
Well, lookie there!!   The very next words from Paul’s quill.  Verse 21.

But now apart from the Law the righteousness of God has been
revealed...


You say you immediately thought "the words are just synonyms". Poor synonyms. Trench's "Synonyms" is the best!

In Trench's "Synonyms" p288 [1976] Trench discusses how "lalei" and "lego" compare. He says:

"...at Rom. 3:19 there is an instructive interchange of the words."

Trench does not dwell on this interchange but goes on to look at e.g., John 8:43 where he sees significance in the particular use of these words. So what is instructive about Rom. 3:19? Is it instructive?
From John 8:12 ESV

"Again Jesus spoke to them, saying, "I am the light of the world."

Here we see "Jesus spoke" [lalei]. He made sounds with His mouth. He said [lego] words with authority and meaning.
From John 8:13

"..your testimony is not true."

The Pharisees heard the sound [lalei] of His words, understood His words, but rejected their meaning  [logos].
The words  [John 8:20 rhemata] that Jesus spoke [lalei] were to the Pharisees sounds that could be rejected. They were not obedient to them. [e.g., obey/hypakouete Romans 6:16]. The Pharisees were not "underhearing" of Jesus' words.
Those under the law are not regenerate [ born again John 3:3], and do not have  ears to hear meaning [logos]. They only hear speech [lalei].
"The law is holy". [ John 7:12]. i.e., full of meaning. The law's words [rhemata] are full of logos. But whatever the law says [lego] it comes across as mere sounds [lalei] to those under the law.
Those under the law are not in the "new way of the Spirit" [Romans 7:6]. Those that are under the law do not comply with it because they do not "have ears to hear". [Matt 11:15].
My conclusion:
Romans 3:19- whatever the law says [lego full of meaning], it speaks [lalei] not authoritatively, or with meaning to those under the law.
In that they do not have ears to hear.

OP asks,

"Does the difference between legei and lalei suggest that those under the law do not have "ears to hear", "


or how else might the difference between these two be described in this verse?"

I would say that the difference between the two words is first of all what is the law saying?
Going back to Romans, 2:13 sums up with the law is saying.

Whoever sinned in law, through law will be judged. For not the listeners to law are just with God, but the doers of the law shall be justified..

Going down to verse 2:10 we see that no one is just not even one.
So the second half of Romans 3:19 is who is the law speaking to? In other words, who is the audience that the law is speaking to?
Paul starts in Romans 2:17 who  is now  his targeted audience.

Now  you, if you call yourself a Jew; if you rely on the law and boast in God; if you know His will and approve of what is superior because you are instructed by the law; if you are convinced that you are a guide for the blind, a light for those in darkness, an instructor of the foolish, a teacher of infants, because you have in the law the embodiment of knowledge and truth.

He is now saying that just because they have the law that does not make them better than the Gentiles .  They too are a slave to sin.
He is telling that no flesh will be justified in his sight, for through the law is a recognition of sin.
Of course, now the good news comes starting in verse 21.
So to summit up with the subtlety of the two words is to know what the law is saying and then the next one who is the law speaking to.

Now we are aware that, whatever the law is saying, it is speaking to those under the law, that every mouth may be barred.  Roman's 3:19


Thanks. I'm a bit confused by your grammar in "they are not just sin like everyone else". Is, "they are sinners like everyone else [despite having the law]" what you mean  or am I still misunderstanding?

C.Stroud Thanks for drawing my attention to that.  I just went ahead and fixed it.  I so appreciate you helping out with my edits along with your thought provoking questions!
